# What is the time complexity of finding a letter in a string?

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory

I have a string called alphanumeric, which contains all letters and numbers.

```
alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
```

I want to iterate over a list of individual characters (some of which are alphanumeric and some which are simply punctuation) to find out which are alphanumeric.  What would the time complexity of the line:

```
if character in alphanumeric:
```

be?  I wasn't sure if strings are considered lists for time complexity, because when looking at the Python wiki (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) the operation "x in s" is considered O(N).

Comment: Please make sure that you really want to ask about time complexity and that you aren't interested in general practical performance. Taking your question literally, the answer is `O(1)` simply because there is no dependence on length-varying input in the line `if character in alphanumeric:`. `alphanumeric` has fixed length and so does `character`.

Comment: The documentation is talking about a case where the list `s` has length `N`. Then indeed it is `O(N)`.

Comment: Strings are not considered lists as far as the time complexity of `in` goes. (Not that it’s wrong for this case – searching *for a single character* in a string with `in` is still O(n) on the length of the string.)

Comment: If you're really worried about performance (even though performance sounds irrelevant for your specific example), use a set instead of a string for containing letters/numbers.

Comment: ""x in s" is considered O(N).", no it's not, its considered O(len S)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your function works like this:

```
FindAlphaNumeric(s:string):string
1. alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
2. result = ""
3. for each c:character in s
4.  if c in alphanumeric then result.append("1") else result.append("0")
5. return result
```

In this case, there is the length of the input, `|s|`, and the length of the constant string, `|alphanumeric|`. The line `if c in alphanumeric then` has time complexity `O(|alphanumeric|)` if you search for `c` using linear search. The overall complexity of the whole algorithm is `O(|s|*|alphanumeric|)`. However, because `alphanumeric` is a constant string, its length is also constant, and the constant can be disregarded: `O(|s|)` is the time complexity. Indeed, the asymptotic complexity as a function of the input size does not depend upon the length of the constant string, or the manner in which membership is determined.